# How to set button under very large WebView on Android?

Tags: android, layout, webview

I have problem with setting button under large muptipage webview (User Agreement). Now I can see the button all the time while scrolling webview.

When I add `android:layout_below="@+id/rl_relativeLayout`to button in layout, I can see only WebView content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <RelativeLayout  
    android:id="@+id/rl_relativeLayout"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"  
    android:layout_margin="10dip" >  
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" 
   />

</RelativeLayout> 

 <RelativeLayout  
    android:id="@+id/rl_relativeLayout2"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"  
    android:layout_margin="10dip" >  
<Button
    android:id="@+id/agreement_acceptance"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"  
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:text="OK" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

```
<ScrollView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"> 

    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <WebView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: It works, thank you very much! I'm sorry, my reputation is low and I can't vote up your answer.

Answer (score 0):

just add webView above the button and the button align to bottom ;)

In your case something like that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <RelativeLayout  
    android:id="@+id/rl_relativeLayout2"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"  
    android:layout_margin="10dip"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >  
<Button
    android:id="@+id/agreement_acceptance"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"  
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:text="OK" />
</RelativeLayout> 

 <RelativeLayout  
    android:id="@+id/rl_relativeLayout"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"  
    android:layout_margin="10dip"
    android:layout_above="@+id/rl_relativeLayout2"
    >  
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" 
   />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Just tried this variant but it didn't work. I can scroll down webview but can't see the button.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/agreement_acceptance"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl_relativeLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dip" >

                <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/web_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/agreement_acceptance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="OK" />
```